# TSQL - Unpivot multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, crosstab, unpivot

How can I unpivot multiple columns in "one"?

Right now I have an unpivot for each column but this creates a lot of empty rows.

See the screenshot please.
[image]

At the top you see the input data. At the moment I'm at the table in the middle with this code:

```
SELECT [ID], [RowNumber],  [Year], [Sales]  FROM (
        SELECT ID, RowNumber, [Sales 2013] as [2013], [Sales 2014] as [2014]
        FROM mytable) p     UNPIVOT (
        [Sales] FOR [Year] IN ([2013], [2014])  )AS unpvt ;
```

But I think it would be much better to get to the bottom table structure since the actual data contains more columns and more years to deal with.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/049aa/10)  with the sample data.

Hope you can show me a way to get there. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT [ID],
       [RowNumber],
       [Year],
       Sales,
       Budget
FROM   mytable
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES (2013, [Sales 2013], [Budget 2013]),
                           (2014, [Sales 2014], [Budget 2014]) ) 
                     V([Year], Sales, Budget)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/049aa/17)

Comment: thanks for both answers - I will go with the one that is easier to read and understand for me :-)

Comment: Great post with support for SQL Fiddle.  That helped me deviate from a dreaded implementation with a possible Frankenstein approach to UnPivot.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to repivot after unpivoting - like so:

```
select [Id], [Year], [Sales], [Budget], [Actual] from
(SELECT [Id],
        Left([Colhead], charindex(' ',[Colhead])-1) [Category],
        Right([Colhead], len([Colhead])-charindex(' ',[Colhead])) [Year],
        [Figures]
 FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) p
       UNPIVOT ([Figures] FOR [Colhead] IN 
                ([Sales 2013],[Sales 2014],[Budget 2013],[Budget 2014],[Actual 2013],[Actual 2014])
      )
 AS unpvt) as u
pivot
(max([Figures]) for [Category] in ([Sales], [Budget], [Actual])) as p
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16ca1/6).